# React ignore .prettierignore file [EDIT: nothing to do with prettier]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, package.json, prettier

I desperately try to keep some escape characters (`\`) in a js file in my React js project, because I need them. But someone is deleting them automatically, I guess it is prettier.
Here is my config :

```
└── src
|   └── folder
|       └── fileToIgnore.js
├──.prettierrc
├──.prettierignore
├── package.json
```

In my `package.json` I have this :

```
{
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,json,css,md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ],
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "lint-staged": "^7.1.2",
    "prettier": "1.13.2",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "start": ". ./scripts/build-vars.sh && react-scripts start",
   ...
  }
}
```

In my `fileToIgnore.js` I have that :

```
/* eslint-disable no-useless-escape */

export const setClickTag = `'use strict';function getParameterByName(a){var b=RegExp('[?&]'+a+'=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);return b&&decodeURIComponent(b[1].replace(/\+/g,' '))}var clickTag=getParameterByName('clickTag');`;
```

In my `.prettierrc` I have that

```
singleQuote: true
trailingComma: all
printWidth: 120
```

**SOLUTION 1**
I tried to create a `.prettierignore` file with that :

```
/src/folder/fileToIgnore.js    
**/src/folder/fileToIgnore.js
src/folder/fileToIgnore.js
src/folder/*.js
```

but it didn't work out

**SOLUTION 2**
I added `// prettier-ignore` before each variable I wanted to ignore, but it didn't work out

**SOLUTION 3**
I tried to modify the `packager.json` like this :

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,json,css,md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ],
    "ignore":["**/src/folder/fileToIgnore.js"]
  },
```

but it wasn't the solution either.

I really am stuck there, I am thinking maybe React is overwriting some parameters ? Or not ? I am lost !
Thanks for your help !!

Comment: You have provided lots of details here, one thing you totally forgot to include is an example were you are wanting to use a `\\` in your JS files.

Comment: well I would ask the question anyway, for the challenge of it ! But if you ask, I put the content of the file in the content of my message. Even if I could use another method other than Regex to reach my goal, I would really like to understand how to make prettier work properly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with prettier, now you have provided an example it's easy to see you are not escaping your strings.

You can't do just `\` in JS, to do a backslash in JS inside a string you need to use `\\`.

Now with that in mind, inside your string you have -> `replace(/\+/g,' ')`, this needs to be `replace(/\\+/g,' ')`due to string escaping.

Comment: Thank you so much !